# How to properly make a call to a Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

In the ASP .NET website they have [an example](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) of how to call a Web API from a .NET Client.

They have this method to make a call which creates a new Product:

```
static async Task<Uri> CreateProductAsync(Product product)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/products", product);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    // Return the URI of the created resource.
    return response.Headers.Location;
}
```

This is like the usual way to make any call to any API in any language or framework, but I see a lot of problems in this line:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/products", product);
```

If the "path" parameter is a string, there is no way to detect possible errors in compilation time. Besides, if the API changes and we have a lot of calls, there is no way to rebuild the calls quickly.

Is there a better way to build the call to avoid this kind of problems? I mean, like we do with Web Services, for instance.

Comment: Short answer: No, that is how HttpClient was designed.

Comment: You don't have to use a magic string. If you store routes in config or database, etc then you can make changes quickly but that won't help with your wanting compile errors.

Comment: Thank's, but how would you do with parameters. For instance, if you have the route `"api/products/{Id}"´ and you save it in another class or database you would have a call like this ´client.PutAsJsonAsync(Routes.Products, product)´, which is not very readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Nkosi mentioned, that is how it is designed. However you could create a class with the API URI's and use those instead of literals

```
public class ApiUris
{
    public const string Products = "api/products";
    public const string Services = "api/services";
    public const string Orders = "api/orders";
    /* ... */
}
```

That way you can easily change the path if your webapi changes.

Comment: Seems good, but still too sensitive to misstype errors and changes. And what about parameters? I mean, imagine "api/products/getproduct/{ProductId}", if this is how is designed, it does not look like well designed to me.

Comment: Well, following that line of thought you will always be prone to misstype, even if you put your urls in a database or resources file... Of course you can parametrize the uri, I don't see how it would be a problem. Are you trying to figure out a way to dinamically build the uri?

Comment: No, I came from WebServices and WCF, where you can do `client.Method(parameter)`. I'm wondering if there is something as good as that in Web API.

Comment: I see. I guess there really isn't something like that built in. Unless you mimic it yourself, however that is what you are trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Even Web Service and WCF service does not gurantee build fail if the server changes the URL or type and/or structure of the parameter. You come to know about the changes only when you call the service and it breaks.

In case of calling Web APIs surely there is no way you can figure out that the URL or the paramemeter is incorrect until you call the API.

At the same time, Web API are not built to be changed frequently. If they are not reliable no one would use them. So if you are using an API you can be sure that they will not change their URL or stop supporting certain input parameters overnight making their consumer applications like yours break. They surely woudn't want to be sued by their customers.

Any API would change gradually and with well advanced notice to their customers so that they get time to change their implementation to support new version of API.
So you can rely on the service which you are using and puting values related to it (such as URLs) in the config file would be good enough. Or you can choose to put API Urls in database so that when it changes you just need to update entry in the database and changes will be effective immediately.

Comment: You are focusing only in the "changes" issue. But what about clean code or coding errors? In WebService you can call any method like `client.Method(parameters)`, there is no way you can miss that. And if the web service changes, you can update the refference with two clicks.

Comment: The clean code is "You should not be recompile your project just becase a small value is changed." That's when configuration files come in picture. You just change your config file and redeploy. And if you put your config in database even redeployment can be avoided.

Comment: About the use case you mentioned of web service, that's valid but not something which is a standard right now. What you are asking is not a use case at all Web API world. When you start integrating with a Web API you need to make sure that everything works fine, all use cases are covered before it goes to production. If you want to have compilation failure if the PayLoad of the web API is not correct, that's something not done so far.

Comment: Well, "not a use case" is only your opinion. In my company we are more than 40 developers working with a Web API developed by another company (and believe me, they make changes). We are having a lot of issues that could be less if we had something more "WebService's style".

Comment: I agree about the the difficulties you have because of frequent changes. If the API is being changed in production environment very frequently without notifying the consuming applications then that's the bad part on the API provider side. And that I would consider the only use case where the API provider is not worrying about the consumer. Is there an instance in past where google, Facebook, AWS, Azure, Twitter change their APIs overnight in production? No. Right? So if that is happening than it's a bad practice I would say.

Comment: To solve the specific coding and quality issue. As an API provider we are thinking of releasing SDKs for each of the languages which will internally call our Web API. Customer only need to worry about calling method from the SDK. So when we change our API we release new version of SDK for the customer well in advance before we deprecate old version of API. But that's the solution we are provideing as a API Provider. As a customer of other APIs we are completely relying on other API providers and we trust them.

Comment: I am actually thinking in create some kind of SDK from our side, which isolates the issues created by the API.

Comment: The most important thing for an API to be trustworthy and successfully is the rock solid documentation. As I said there is not compiletime failure so customer always rely on the information available about the API. And also as a consumer of the API you also should make sure that the documentation is understood properly before and during the integration. But it can help very little if API itself is not stable.

Answer (score -1):

Just extending upon Adam's solution you can get a List of your routes using

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.ToList();
```

Then getting the path depends on the concrete implementation of the RouteBase abstract class.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how can this be an answer for my question.

Comment: I was thinking you can use this way to populate fx. static class container for your routes. You could then develop some kind of service contract but then again you are developing an overhead upon a REST-ish service that is starting to resemble SOAP.

Comment: Enabling the generated [help pages](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages)  has proven quite useful for me and is often overlooked.